# SonataAdmin hooks are not firing

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have Symfony 2.8. I use SonataAdminBundle v2.3 + a2lix/TranslationFormBundle v2.1 + SonataMediaBundle v2.3. I have `NewsAdmin` class:

```
class NewsAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', ['fields' => [
                'content' => [
                    'field_type' => 'ckeditor',
                ]
            ]])
            ->add('excerptImage', 'sonata_type_model_list', [], [
                'link_parameters' => ['context' => 'default'],
                'require' => false
            ])
            ->add('excerptImageSide')
            ->add('category', 'sonata_type_model', [
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\NewsCategory',
                'property' => 'shortName'
            ])
        ;
    }

    // configureDatagridFilters(), configureListFields() ...

    // Does not firing!
    public function postUpdate($news)
    {
        dump('preUpdate');
    }

    // Does not firing!
    public function prePersist($news)
    {
        dump('prePersist');
    }
}
```

The problem is that nor `postUpdate`, nor `prePersist` methods are not firing, so I don't see in web profiler string 'preUpdate' or 'prePersist'. Why that happens? And how to fix that?

P.S. Please, let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `die` and you'll see your `dump`.

```
public function prePersist($news)
{
    dump('prePersist');
    die;
}
```

**EDIT**

That's because the `dump` is not called directly from the controller action that renders the view, nor from a method called by the action, but in an EventListener that is totally standalone.

Comment: Thank you, now it works! But can you please provide me any links, which confirm your words? Because, for example in code: `$foo = [1, 2, 3, 4]; print_r($foo); for ($i = 0; $i < 300; $i++) {}`  I see `print_r` result in spite of there is operation after it.

Comment: I updated my answer, my words were totally badly chosen.